# Convertir fecha a número en MySQL (como en Excel)

Tags: mysql, date, integer, datos

Tengo la siguiente fecha **2003/01/01** su valor numérico en Excel es **37622** internamente obtenido por una diferencia de días tomando como fecha base el día 1899-12-30, quisiera realizar lo mismo en MySQL.

*Muchas gracias por la ayuda prestada.*

Comment: Hola. Disculpa, no se entiende a qué te refieres con "lo mismo". Ese valor en excel es una representación que hace excel de la fecha (por eso puede darle formato si pones la celda con formato fecha). De nuevo, qué es lo que deseas hacer en mysql? En todos los datos en una columna? en un único datos? qué has intentado y por qué no funciona? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade esta info. PD. Evita las mayúsculas sostenidas.

Comment: Buen dia, la cosa es asi en excel en "Formato de celda" FORMATO FECHA es asi 09/09/2017 y si lo cambiamos FORMATO NUMERICO la misma fecha es: 42987,00. La pregunta es como lo puedo hacer en sql query. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente sentencia en MySQL, según el contenido de tu pregunta la fecha cero utilizada por tu versión de Excel es '1899-12-30', por ello, debes obtener la diferencia de días tomando esa fecha como base:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF('2003-01-01','1899-12-30') AS date
```

Agrego evidencia del resultado de la ejecución de la anterior sentencia SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Para esta ejecución se utilizó 8.0.22 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: Buen dia, la cosa es asi en excel en "Formato de celda" FORMATO FECHA es asi 09/09/2017 y si lo cambiamos FORMATO NUMERICO la misma fecha es: 42987,00. La pregunta es como lo puedo hacer en sql query. gracias

Comment: En efecto, la respuesta que le ofrezco cumple con esta funcionalidad, he anexado una imagen de evidencia utilizando esta setencia SQL en MySQL Community Server 8.0.22 - GPL.